# scrape data into JSON using lxml

Tags: python, lxml

I'm trying to scrape data using lxml. In the html i have a line like this:

```
<p class="datetime is-upcomming">March 10, Tuesday, 18:00 CET</p>
```

From this i've created a function which could look like this

```
def get_date(self):
    request = requests.get(self.url)
    tree = html.fromstring(request.content)
    theDate = tree.xpath("//p[@class='datetime is-upcomming']/text()")
    if not theDate:
        theDate = ''
    return theDate
```

Then i'm trying to save into JSON using this function:

```
def __dict__(self, get_streams=False):
    data = {
        'game': self.game,
        'title': self.title,
    }
    data['start_date'] = self.get_date()
```

Why does this return a array? and why is it empty?

```
"start_date": [
""
]
```

And yes i have double checked that there actually is a class with datetime is-upcomming

Comment: Could you share the value of `self.url`? Thanks.

Comment: _Why does this return a array_ - which method are you referring to? Your `__dict__` doesn't return anything and since it shadows the object's `__dict__` used to hold instance attributes, you may just be seeing a local variable named `start_date`.

Comment: I think your first step is to rename `def _dict__(..)` to something else. You shouldn't be shadowing the object `__dict__` with a method.

Answer (score 0):

> Why does this return a array? and why is it empty?

Because this always returns a list, an empty list if nothing is found.

Your xpath is probably incorrect, can you post the entire doc or where to find it?

Also, why use `__dict__` instead of a new method for this? `__dict__` is the instance attribute dictionary, I wouldn't mess with that unless you know what you are doing.

Comment: Or the value is set by javascript and `request.content` contains the element with an empty text. I've already asked for the link in the comments :) Let's wait.

Comment: @alecxe I see, that. Sorry I thought you were OP at first.

Comment: It is an API which i'm trying to edit. i'm trying to add the start_date attriute from the site. The dict is the person who made the API, who made it. I guess he knows what his doing :)